# Can't wget from github, sslv3 handshake error

Tags: centos, wget, github

We have a script that downloads mod security from github that has recently started failing. The servers run CentOS 6 but RHEL 6 probably has the same issue. The output is:

```
# wget https://github.com/downloads/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/modsecurity-apache_2.7.1.tar.gz
--2014-07-22 18:49:46--  https://github.com/downloads/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/modsecurity-apache_2.7.1.tar.gz
Resolving github.com... 192.30.252.129
Connecting to github.com|192.30.252.129|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://cloud.github.com/downloads/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/modsecurity-apache_2.7.1.tar.gz [following]
--2014-07-22 18:49:47--  https://cloud.github.com/downloads/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/modsecurity-apache_2.7.1.tar.gz
Resolving cloud.github.com... 54.230.99.219, 205.251.219.190, 54.230.97.212, ...
Connecting to cloud.github.com|54.230.99.219|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Any ideas on how to fix or work around this?

Comment: use another application, e.g `curl`

Comment: To be more specific, both 54.230.99.219 and several of the (different) A's I get for cloud.github.com give handshake failure to s_client without option for ServerNameIndication. http://serverfault.com/questions/560053/curl-succeeds-on-an-https-request-wget-does-not says (several months ago) RedHat wget doesn't do SNI but curl does.

Comment: You feel lucky to accept my **[answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146010/50478)**

Comment: Well, to be honest I would prefer if @dave_thompson_085 or Rabin posted their comments as answers as I see that as more of a long term solution even though your workaround also works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you mean this **[repo](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity)**. Try to get URL form **[Releases](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/releases)**.

This case work for me:

```
$ wget https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/archive/v2.8.0.tar.gz
```

P.S. I also have the same error message when try to run your case;

```
$ wget https://github.com/downloads/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/modsecurity-apache_2.7.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Hmm, this URL does not have an md5 though :(

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${USER}/${REPO}/path/to/file.tar.gz

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `curl` command to download it:

```
curl -LO https://github.com/downloads/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/modsecurity-apache_2.7.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: `curl -L -O` is a better replacement for `wget`, since it follows HTTP redirects (particularly useful here since Github wants to point me to its CDN).

Comment: Also, one thing I ran into with the versions in CentOS 6.5 is that `curl` supports SNI and `wget` does not, so for some sites `wget` will sometimes be served the certificate for the wrong host and get a certificate failure, even if `curl` works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Server side has disabled the SSLv3 encryption handshake, because of SSLv3 severe security issues. 
Moreover, your wget client is an outdated version and still use as default this SSLv3 encryption. You have 2 options:

- use --secure-protocol=TLSv1 flag in front of wget. 
  `wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1`
- install an updated version of wget that use as default TLSv1 protocol

Answer (score 5):

You should check your wget version.

I had the same problem with older versions of `wget` (< 1.15).

Comment: This looks like this should be a comment against the question, and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for workaround, if you trust the host try specifying `--no-check-certificate` or add:

```
check_certificate = off
```

into your `~/.wgetrc` (not recommended).

In some rare cases, it's caused by your system time which could be out-of-sync therefore invalidating the certificates which was working before.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind editing your post to include some explanation, i.e. in particular which of the symptoms described by the OP leads you to conclude that the crypto policies are the issue, and why changing them in this way can solve them? The idea is to have answers as self-contained as possible so that they are useful not only to the OP, but others facing similar problems, too.

Comment: If this is the tool introduced by RHEL 8, you should say that, and also realize that this question is about RHEL6.